# Is there a math function that takes in a number n and return a number with the digits of n sorted by value?

Tags: functions, summation, arithmetic

The idea crossed my mind of a function that would take in an integer *n* and return an integer of the digits of *n* in order.

e.g:
*g*(184729) = 987421
*g*(1212121212) = 2222211111
*g*(1234567890) = 9876543210

I looked it up and saw a similar question, but the answer did not satisfy me as I was looking for one using only basic arithmetic operations, summations, logarithme and modulo.

Comment: Were I automating it, I'd do so recursively.  Note that the answer is always a $10-$tuple of non-negative integers (telling you how many $9's, 8's, \cdots$ you need).  Now you just read off the first digit, increment the relevant index by $1$, and proceed.

Comment: are you suggesting having a function that returns how many of each number you have, so that f(9333381) = 1100004010 and then read this number 1 digit at a time to build the sorted output ?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  That way I only need to store the current $10-$tuple.

Comment: Should say, just as a matter of notation, I wouldn't write the $10-$ tuple as a string the way you did.  I'd write $9833331$ as $(1,1,0,0,0,0,4,0,1,0)$.  The way you wrote it would be ambiguous if there were more than $9$ of any given digit(s).

Comment: True, thats what I was about to say. That was actually my first try and worked well until you have more than 9 time the same digit. I changed approach and calculate them individually in my answer because I wanted to avoid storing numbers in an array

Comment: In Mathematica you’d convert the number to its list of digits, sort the list, then reconvert back to the original number.

Comment: That's how you'd do it in any programming language

Answer (score 0):

So the answer I came up with might not be the best, but I am satisfied with it.
I splited the following answer in 4 functions (for obvious reasons) but it can be made into one single function.

First, *i*(x,*n*) returns the *n*th digit of x
$i\left(x,n\right)=\left\lfloor\operatorname{mod}\left(\frac{x}{10^{n}},10\right)\right\rfloor$

*c*(x)+1 returns the length of x
$c\left(x\right)=\left\lfloor\log\left(x\right)\right\rfloor$

*f*(x,n) counts how many time the digit *n* is in x
$f\left(x,n\right)=\sum_{p=0}^{c\left(x\right)}0^{\left|i\left(x,p\right)-\operatorname{mod}\left(n,10\right)\right|}$

Finally, *g*(x) checks *f*(x) for how many time each digit is in x, multiply them by $\frac{1}{9}$ multiply by 10 one last time so the summation of digits don't overlap
$g\left(x\right)=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{9}\left\lfloor\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)\cdot10^{f\left(x,n\right)}\right\rfloor\cdot n\cdot10^{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f\left(x,k\right)}\right)\cdot10^{f\left(x,0\right)}$

Comment: What does $\mathrm{mod}(x,y)$ mean?

Comment: I may not have formatted it the correct way, but its modulus, or remainder operation. Mod (x,y) would return what remains of x after substracting y the maximum number of time. So mod(43,10) returns 3, because after substracting 10 4 times you are left with 3.

Comment: If $x = 358$ and $n=2$, I take $\mathrm{mod}(3.58,10)$.  What does it mean to take the remainder of a decimal number mod $10$?

Comment: since you can't substract 10 from 3.58, you are left with 3.58, which is the floored to 3

Comment: OK, so that returns the first (third?) digit of $x$, not the 2nd.

Comment: Excatly, because the count starts at n=0, so i(358,0) returns the first digit. c(x) also returns the number of digit-1, so c(123456) returns 5, not 6, because the first digit counts as 0